# Scope nested associations in controller on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to 'fix' Unscoped Find warnings from brakeman in Rails 5.

the thing is that I have nested relationships and I realized after run brakeman that I can access to any object in database that is unscoped.

I have this relationships in my models:

```
class Medic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patients, dependent: :destroy
  validates_associated :patients
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :medic
  has_many :consultations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :consultations
  validates_associated :consultations
end

class Consultation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :prescriptions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prescriptions
  validates_associated :prescriptions
end
```

so, when I try to scope in a callback in controllers, by this way:

#### controllers/patients_controller.rb

```
  private
    def set_patient
      @patient = current_medic.patients.find(params[:id]) # this scope works
    end
```

#### controllers/consultations_controller.rb

```
  before_action :set_patient
  before_action :set_consultation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...code...
  private
    def set_consultation
      @consultation = @patient.consultations.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_patient
      @patient = current_medic.patients.find_by_id(params[:patient_id])
    end
```

**@consultation = @patient.consultations.find(params[:id])** this scope don't work "*undefined method `consultations' for nil:NilClass*" only work if I do Consultation.find(params[:id]), but in this way anyone can access to any consultation if put X id as parameter /consultations/3 despite that this consultation do not belong to any patient associated to the user

#### controllers/prescriptions_controller.rb

```
  before_action :set_consultation
  before_action :set_prescription, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...code...
  private
  def set_prescription
    @prescription = Prescription.find(params[:id]) # the same here, object consultation is 'nil' @consultation.prescriptions.find(params[:id]) won't work
  end

  def set_consultation
    @consultation = Consultation.find_by_id(params[:consultation_id])
  end
```

my tests are failing in show, edit, update and destroy. For example.

#### consultations_controller_test.rb with minitest

```
  test "should show consultation" do
    get consultation_url(id: @consultation.id)
    assert_response :success # expected response 2XX but get error 500
  end
```

#### My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :medics

  resources :patients, shallow: true do
    resources :consultations
  end

  resources :consultations, shallow: true do
    resources :prescriptions
  end
end
```

How can I scope this nested relationships?